# Query Mysql Producto Categoria Subcategoria

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo esta relacion:

[image: Base de Datos Tablas Relacionadas]

Y Quisiera hacer la consulta adecuada que me arrojara los Productos que pertenecen unicamente a una Subcategoria, de una Categoria en especifico.

Si pudiesen ayudarme se los agradeceria, le estoy dando vueltas, pero aun los JOIN me enrredan un poco y aun no he logrado hacerlo funcional.

Estoy abierto a sugerencias, si la relacion no es la adecuada, aun asi, y por supuesto que estare tomando la sugerencia, quisiera si fuera factible el Query que me arrojara el resultado tal como esta en este momento.

Gracias de antemano.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta consulta te traera todos los productos con sus respectivas categorias, subcategorias, etc.
Tener en cuenta que: La sentencia JOIN (unir, combinar) de SQL permite combinar registros de una o más tablas en una base de datos relacional.

`select 
        p.id, p.nombre_prod, c.nombre_cat, s.nombre_subCat 
    from 
        producto p 
    join
        prod_cat_subcat pcs on pcs.id_prod = p.id
    join
        categoria c on c.id = pcs.id_cat
    join
        subcategoria s on s.id = pcs.id_subcat
where s.id = 1;`

Si te interesa solamente los datos sin importar si estan cargados en las demas tablas puedes utilizar left join:
El resultado de esta operación siempre contiene todos los registros de la tabla de la izquierda (Productos), independientemente de si existe un registro correspondiente en la tabla de la derecha (Categoria, subcategoria, etc).

`select 
        p.id, p.nombre_prod, c.nombre_cat, s.nombre_subCat 
    from 
        producto p 
    left join
        prod_cat_subcat pcs on pcs.id_prod = p.id
    left join
        categoria c on c.id = pcs.id_cat
    left join
        subcategoria s on s.id = pcs.id_subcat
where s.id = 1;`

Comment: postear respuestas que solo son código se consideran de baja calidad; considera poner una explicación

Comment: disculpas @shadow

Comment: Gracias @omelgarejo por tu tiempo. La consulta efectivamente me devuelve en el resultado del Query los elementos relacionados. Pero, busca una manera que dinamicamente pueda extraer unicamente ese elemento de dicha subcategoria, ya que el fin es. Llenar una pagina de Subcategorias, donde por ejemplo. Solo estan los Cafes, y unicamente necesito los Cafes que estan en la Categoria de Cafes, Subcategoria Cafe Negro. por ejemplo.

Comment: Esta subcategoria, yo pasaria el ID por PHP para que me devuelva exactamente los productos de ella. Espero haberme explicado, y tu comprendido jaja. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: A ver, quieres filtrar todos los productos de una determinada categoria o subcategoria?

Comment: exacto como veras en las tablas, la subcategoria pertenece a categorias tiene una FK, y a su vez, enlazo producto-categoria-subcategoria en una tabla, para determinar que producto pertenece a que categoria, y en ella, a que subcategoria. 

Yo necesito llenar una Pagina de Subcategoria con los productos que sean de esa Subcategoria.

Comment: entonces al final de la consulta debes filtrar de la siguiente manera:  where s.id = 1; asumiendo que 1 es el ID de la subcategoria.

Comment: @omelgarejo Cierto! era sencillamente agregar eso. Cuando uno esta ofuscado no ve nada. Gracias amigo por tu tiempo.

Comment: De nada @J'Esaa

Answer (score 0):

cómo puedo definir una categoria random a un id desde un formulario de forma random? O sea que el formulario suba el producto con categoria aleatoria, de forma de queden los productos distribuidos ascendentemente pero con diferentes categorias, digamos que existan sólo tres categorias diferentes y 200 id